# macro like functionality in python django

Tags: python, django, macros

I have some django view handler functions which are structured like this

```
def view1(request):

  # Check for authorization
  if not isAuthorized(request):
    return HttpResponse('Foo error', status=401)

  return HttpResponse('view1 data')


def view2(request):

  # Check for authorization
  if not isAuthorized(request):
    return HttpResponse('Foo error', status=401)

  return HttpResponse('view2 data')


def view3(request):

  # Check for authorization
  if not isAuthorized(request):
    return HttpResponse('Foo error', status=401)

  return HttpResponse('view3 data')
```

I want to make this part :

```
  # Check for authorization
  if not isAuthorized(request):
    return HttpResponse('Foo error', status=401)
```

some sort of one-liner, so that I do not have to repeat it in each view

In C this would have been a macro, but I've no clue how to achieve something similar in python

The check authorization function part is an example, it can be any check which has nothing to do with user authorization in particular

[Edit]

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2337736/peter-deglopper mentions decorators ...

To elaborate

I have a web API that can take either POST or GET

```
# return either GET or POST dict whichever exists
def getParams(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return request.GET
    return request.POST
```

The views do this :

```
def someAPI(request):
  dct = getParams(request)

  if not isValid(dct):
    return HttpResponse('Bad request', status=401)
```

How could I acheive this with a decorator? I have that getParams() function in between....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you'd use view decorators for this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/

There's a built in one for checking login status:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator

And one for arbitrary tests on the authenticated user:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test

A full example adapted from http://mrcoles.com/blog/3-decorator-examples-and-awesome-python/:

```
from functools import wraps

def validate_params(view_func):
    def _decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
        dct = getattr(request, request.METHOD)
        if not isValid(dct):
            return HttpResponse('Bad request', status=401)
        else:
            response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            return response
    return wraps(view_func)(_decorator)
```

I'm using `getattr` rather than an `if/then` on `request.METHOD` - I think that's cleaner. If you like you could still use your `getParams` call instead.

Comment: As I said, this is not quite django user auth specific. I want to run an arbitrary function that checks the GET/POST in the request and returns an error sometimes.

Can decorators do this?

Comment: Yes - if you check the source for the method required decorator you'll see an example of returning an error response based on the `request`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/views/decorators/http/#require_http_methods

Comment: Although that one's a little more complicated than you might need because the decorator itself takes arguments. The "basic decorator" example here looks right to me if you want to make the same check all the time: http://mrcoles.com/blog/3-decorator-examples-and-awesome-python/

Comment: Edited in an example showing how you can integrate your parameter checking.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

As Peter says, decorators are an ideal solution for this. But an alternative is to use class-based views: you can define a base class that does the checking, and subclasses that implement the specific behaviour.